# Overriding the logging methods (logger.warn) in slf4j

Tags: log4j, overriding, extend, slf4j

What is the easiest way to extend the functionality of the logger.warn method?

Consider the code:

```
logger.warn("Invalid value ({}). Defaulting to UNKNOWN.", value);
```

I also want to print a stack trace - or do something else special every time I encounter an warning.  For instance:

```
logger.warn("Invalid value ({}). Defaulting to UNKNOWN.", value);
for (StackTraceElement stackTraceElement:Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()) {
  logger.warn(stackTraceElement.toString());
}
```

I would like to be able to put the 'for loop' in the logger method.  something like.

```
public void warn (String s, Object o) {
  super(s, o);
  for (StackTraceElement stackTraceElement:Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()) {
    logger.warn(stackTraceElement.toString());
  }
}
```

Is there an easy way to extend the logger to do that?

Comment: Have you considered the `logger.warn("...{}", value, new RuntimeException("for log"))` variant?

Answer (score 0):

[Markers](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Marker.html), which are part of the SLF4J API is the way to go. Unfortunately, only the logback framework which natively implements the SLF4J API supports markers. Moreover, logback's %caller conversion specified already supports the use case you describe out-of-the-box.

You would add the %caller [conversion word](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#conversionWord) to your pattern. For example, "%d %t %logger - %m%n%caller{2, WITH_CALLER_MARKER}" where WITH_CALLER_MARKER denotes an [evaluator](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#Evaluators).  In this configuration, if the WITH_CALLER_MARKER evaluator returns true, 3 lines of caller data will be printed.

The evaluator would be specified as follows in the logback.xml config file.

```
<evaluator name="WITH_CALLER_MARKER" 
           class="ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.OnMarkerEvaluator">
  <marker>WITH_CALLER</marker>
</evaluator>
```

Enabling caller info is now as easy as logging with the "WITH_CALLER" marker. Here is an example,

```
Marker withCallerMaker = MarkerFactory.getMarker("WITH_CALLER");
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("some.name");
logger.warn(withCallerMarker, "Invalid value {}. Defaulting to UNKNOWN.", value);
```

Since you are already using SLF4J, migrating to logback is trivially easy. Just convert your log4j.properties file to logback.xml, remove slf4j-log4j12.jar, and replace log4j.jar with logback-*.jar and you are done. There is even a [tool to translate](http://logback.qos.ch/translator/) log4j.properties files to logback.xml.

I am afraid achieving similar functionality with log4j would involve much more work and the end result would not be nearly as convenient.

Comment: First, thank you for the suggestion.  Q: if I change to the logback framework, and then implement code specific to that framework, then I guess I do not need SLF4J which is intended to allow me to switch logging frameworks?

Comment: In the example above, you are just configuring logback. There is *no* custom java code involved. More importantly, your code would still depend on the [tag:SLF4J] API not logback. Even if you had to write a custom appender or conversion specifier (which in this case you don't have to), as long as your code uses only the SLF4J API, your dependence on logback would be zero in practical terms. Assuming you are currently using log4j, you have a minimal and uncompressible dependency on log4j.properties. By moving to logback, you would have a minimal and uncompressible dependency on logback.xml.